# adding data to the same set of properties in a class

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to create a JSON file like so:

```
"payload": {
        "control": [
            {
                "option": "SUBSCRIBER_PREAMBLE",
                "value": "XXXX"
            },
            {
                "option": "SUBSCRIBER_OPERATOR_INITIAL",
                "value": "RR"
            }
]
}
```

In order to achieve this, I created two classes like so:

```
public class control
{

    public string option { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}



  public class payloadData
    {
        public payloadData()
        {
            control = new List<control>();
        }
        public List<control> control { get; set; }
    }
```

I put the values to the properties like so:

```
        payloadData pay = new payloadData();
        control con = new control();
        con.option= "SUBSCRIBER_PREAMBLE";
        con.value = "XXXX";
        pay.control.Add(con);
        id.payLoad.Add(pay);
        con.option = "SUBSCRIBER_OPERATOR_INITIAL";
        con.value = "RR";
        pay.control.Add(con);
```

when the JSON is created, I am getting the SUBSCRIBER_OPERATOR_INITIAL option and RR value. Earlier value is overwritten by the next value. I want all the option and values to be added in the JSON. How can I achieve this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to do `con = new control();` after `id.payLoad.Add(pay);`

Comment: What is "id" in your case?

Comment: id is another class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are `not` adding new controls to the list. In your case the below code will help:

```
payloadData pay = new payloadData();
pay.control.Add(new control { option = "SUBSCRIBER_PREAMBLE", value = "XXXX" });
pay.control.Add(new control { option = "SUBSCRIBER_OPERATOR_INITIAL", value = "RR" });
id.payLoad.Add(pay);
```

Comment: Glad to know :)